# Errors in nodes size and color when drawing large graphs with matplotlib

Tags: colors, matplotlib, size, networkx

I'm drawing large graphs with networkx and I'm experiencing problems when graphs are large. For small graphs everything goes ok, but for large graphs (1k nodes) it seems to fail in assigning color and size. 
Here it is the piece of code in question

```
H=nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)[0]
d=nx.degree(H)
b=nx.eigenvector_centrality(H)
pos2=nx.spring_layout(H,scale=2)

labels={}
colors={}
dim={}

for n in H.nodes():
    i=0 
    for v in b:
        if v==n:
            break
        i+=1
    colors[n]=b.values()[i]
    j=0
    for w in d:
        if w==n:
            break
        j+=1
    dim[n]=d.values()[j]*40

    k=0
    for z in range(2):
        if n in sorted(b.items(), key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)[z]:
            labels[n]=n


nx.draw(H,
             pos2,
             with_labels=False,
             node_size=dim.values(),
             node_color=colors.values(),
             cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
             vmin=min(b.values()),
             vmax=max(b.values())   
)
```

I can't post images because I have not enough reputation, but when I say that it fails I mean that (some) nodes with low connectivity are bigger then nodes with high connectivity, and the same happens with color.

Any idea of what it's going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: put them some place and include a link.  A high-rep user and edit them into your post.

Comment: here it is the small graph example https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgwiop394cgik7j/ex1.png
and her the zoom of a big one
https://www.dropbox.com/s/paustbt0wci75cl/ex2.png

Comment: SO seems to not like drop box links.....

Comment: And I think your problem is that you are passing in lists for `node_size` and `node_color`, try just passing in the dictionaries.

Comment: another one
the small graph http://i.tinyuploads.com/B7Yz6n.png
the big graph http://i.tinyuploads.com/EdFT11.png

Comment: If I pass a dictionary it doesn't works. The argument must be a list, I think

Answer (score 0):

Pass the keyword nodelist= with the nodes you want drawn. Then set the node_color and node_size arguments with the colors and sizes in a list with the same ordering.

```
nodes = H.nodes()

nx.draw(H, pos2, nodelist=nodes,
        node_size = [dim[n] for n in nodes],
        node_color= [colors[n] for n in nodes],
        cmap=plt.cm.Reds,
        vmin=min(b.values()),
        vmax=max(b.values()),
        with_labels=False
)
```